# how to append data into excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel

```
designation table:

deg_no  deg_name
1   XYZ
2   ABC
3   pqs 
4   qwe
5   tyu
6   pqr
7   lkj
8   you
9   zzz
10  xxx


ds = cls.ReturnDataSet("RetriveData_Alias1",
         new SqlParameter("@Field", "deg_no"),
        new SqlParameter("@TblNm", "designation"));


for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    ds1 = cls.ReturnDataSet("RetriveData_Alias1",
      new SqlParameter("@Field", "user_id,user_name"),
      new SqlParameter("@TblNm", "User_details"),
      new SqlParameter("@WhereClause", "where deg_no ='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["deg_no"].ToString() + "' "));
}
```

this for loop will run until the deg_no=10 and gives the all the user details and it is gives the perfect output as i want
the output.

but i want to write these data into excel file : user_details.xls

for suppose when i=1, then it will give you

```
user_id   user_name    deg_no
1          xyz      1
```

and for i=2

```
user_id   user_name    deg_no
2          pqr      3
```

and so on...

but without create new file each time .

suppose on first loop it will insert record of user_id =1
then in second loop the details of user_id=2 is append in the same file without creating a new file.

how can i do that?

Comment: I recommend using EPPlus library in projects where you have to work with Excel worksheets (2007 and newer). It does not use interop components and therefore you don't need Office installed where you use it: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You Need to read about ASP.Net Report Viewer control

May this helping you

[ASP.Net Report Viewer control Tutorial with example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Report-Viewer-control-Tutorial-with-example.aspx)

or you can use

[Export to EXCEL from Datatable in C#.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/344604/Export-to-EXCEL-from-Datatable-in-Csharp-Net)

or You need Office Interop as a reference then lets do the coding

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public void DataSetsToExcel(List<DataSet> dataSets, string fileName)
{
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = 
          new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
Sheets xlSheets = null;
Worksheet xlWorksheet = null;

foreach (DataSet dataSet in dataSets)
{
    System.Data.DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
    int rowNo = dataTable.Rows.Count;
    int columnNo = dataTable.Columns.Count;
    int colIndex = 0;

    //Create Excel Sheets
    xlSheets = xlWorkbook.Sheets;
    xlWorksheet = (Worksheet)xlSheets.Add(xlSheets[1], 
                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    xlWorksheet.Name = dataSet.DataSetName;

    //Generate Field Names
    foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        colIndex++;
        xlApp.Cells[1, colIndex] = dataColumn.ColumnName;
    }

    object[,] objData = new object[rowNo, columnNo];

    //Convert DataSet to Cell Data
    for (int row = 0; row < rowNo; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < columnNo; col++)
        {
            objData[row, col] = dataTable.Rows[row][col];
        }
    }

    //Add the Data
    Range range = xlWorksheet.Range[xlApp.Cells[2, 1], xlApp.Cells[rowNo + 1, columnNo]];
    range.Value2 = objData;

    //Format Data Type of Columns 
    colIndex = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        colIndex++;
        string format = "@";
        switch (dataColumn.DataType.Name)
        {
            case "Boolean":
                break;
            case "Byte":
                break;
            case "Char":
                break;
            case "DateTime":
                format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
                break;
            case "Decimal":
                format = "$* #,##0.00;[Red]-$* #,##0.00";
                break;
            case "Double":
                break;
            case "Int16":
                format = "0";
                break;
            case "Int32":
                format = "0";
                break;
            case "Int64":
                format = "0";
                break;
            case "SByte":
                break;
            case "Single":
                break;
            case "TimeSpan":
                break;
            case "UInt16":
                break;
            case "UInt32":
                break;
            case "UInt64":
                break;
            default: //String
                break;
        }
        //Format the Column accodring to Data Type
        xlWorksheet.Range[xlApp.Cells[2, colIndex], 
              xlApp.Cells[rowNo + 1, colIndex]].NumberFormat = format;
    }
}

//Remove the Default Worksheet
((Worksheet)xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count]).Delete();

//Save
xlWorkbook.SaveAs(fileName,
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

xlWorkbook.Close();
xlApp.Quit();
GC.Collect();
}
```

Take note you have to name your DataSet and that will be the name of the worksheet in Excel.

```
DataSet dataSet1 = new DataSet("My Data Set 1");
dataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet1);

DataSet dataSet2 = new DataSet("My Data Set 2");
dataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet2);

DataSet dataSet3 = new DataSet("My Data Set 3");
dataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet3);

List<DataSet> dataSets = new List<DataSet>();
dataSets.Add(dataSet1);
dataSets.Add(dataSet2);
dataSets.Add(dataSet3);

DataSetsToExcel(dataSets, "{Your File Name}")
```

to add Office Interop as a reference

> following these steps:

```
On the Project menu, click Add Reference.
On the COM tab, locate Microsoft Excel Object Library, and then click Select. In Visual Studio 2010, locate Microsoft Excel --.- Object Library on the COM tab.
Click OK in the Add References dialog box to accept your selections. If you are prompted to generate wrappers for the libraries that you selected, click “Yes”.
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont want the RDLC report and also i dont have the datagrid.

Comment: do you need to export to multiple Excel sheets ?

Comment: it is not mandatory...it can be in same sheet. .and if it is in different sheets then it is also fine.

Comment: namespace "office" does not exist in the namespace 'microsoft'

Comment: did you add the Office Interop as a reference

Comment: from where i can find the office interop ?

Comment: i have added that ref but still i got the same error

Comment: when i add that ref then it will add "vwd.webinfo" file i am using visual studio 2012

Comment: try to find an add the Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *generate* an Excel file from database data, a reporting solution is the most flexible approach. If on the other hand you want to add the data to an already existing file, you can manipulate Excel files using the [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx) or a higher-level library like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). EPPlus is available as a NuGet package so you can easily add it to your project.

The project site of EPPlus contains various samples. Creating an Excel sheet can be as simple as :

```
        FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\sample6.xlsx");

        ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
        //Add the Content sheet
        var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");
        ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "Name";
        ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "Size";
        ws.Cells["D1"].Value = "Created";
        ws.Cells["E1"].Value = "Last modified";
```

EPPlus also allows you to query Excel Sheets using LINQ and even directly convert IEnumerable collections to Excel Tables :

```
ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(myList, true);
```

This will fill a table with the property values of the objects in myList.

EPPlus also has methods to read from DataTables and DataReaders. This allows you to read your DataSet as you already do, then add each Datatable to the sheet in the appropriate places, eg:

```
ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(ds1.Tables[0], true);
...
ws.Cells["A30"].LoadFromDataTable(ds1.Tables[0], true);
```

This way you can use EPPlus to generate quick&dirty Excel reports when you don't want to use a full reporting solution.